# Getting a black box type texts on other activities after exiting the game activity

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am getting a black box type texts on other activities after exiting the cocos2d game activity. screenshot attached below.: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5r63sn90ftpu3so/Screenshot%202015-01-26%2015.58.06.png?dl=0

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

i have used cocos2d-android-1 as the library for this project: https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d

Found similar issue on cocos2d-x web site but didn't able to find a solve for cocos2d-android-1: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/8305

Any solution for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please only add tags relevant to the question (and answer). You're not using cocos2d-iphone nor cocos2d-x nor libgdx. You only risk getting an answer for the wrong library by including those, and possibly less likely to get an answer at all because people can't judge by the tags whether the question applies to their expertise or not.

Comment: ok, sorry i understand.